# "Не" с глаголами

Tags: орфография

Насколько я помню, по школьной программе, есть семь исключений слитного написания частицы "не", с глаголами:
ненавидеть, невзлюбить, негодовать, недоумевать, неистовствовать, нездоровится и неможется. Но слышал, что есть ещё исключения, кроме этих.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно слова, перечисленные Вами, объясняются как пишущиеся слитно, потому что без НЕ они не употребляются. Нет необходимости запоминать какой-то длинный список.